# Indexacion query consulta SQL

Tags: sql, join

Hol@ a todos!!!

Junto con Saludar les comento que estoy tratando de resolver un acertijo de *SQL* , el cual aun no he logrado descifrar por lo que acudo a su ayuda por si alguien conoce como podría resolverlo.

Estoy tratando de listar el cliente que mas ha comprado con la cantidad total de compras realizadas y el monto total de la misma.

Tengo 3 Tablas

```
Tabla Cliente
      ClienteID (PK) INT
      Nombre         VARCHAR
      Ciudad         VARCHAR

Table Venta
      VentaID(PK)     INT
      ProductoID(FK)  INT
      clienteID(FK)   INT
      TotalPrice      MONEY
      Cantidad        INT


Tabla Producto
      ProductID(PK)  INT
      NombreProducto VARCHAR
```

Mi query realizada es la siguiente:

```
Select TOP 1 p.*, d.COMPRAS
From (
    SELECT a.ClienteID, SUM(Cantidad) as COMPRAS
    from dbo.Venta a
    GROUP by a.ClienteID
    ) d inner join dbo.Cliente p on d.ClienteID = p.ClienteID
order by COMPRAS desc
```

Esta consulta me muestra el cliente que mas ha comprado con la cantidad total, pero no encuentro como unir el `precioTotal` a la salida y como sumaría todos los valores.

Desde ya agradezco a tod@s!

Comment: ¿Qué motor de base de datos utilizas? ¿Qué columnas esperas obtener en la salida?

Comment: ¿ Sabes si el motor es o no Casesentitive (sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas) ? porque en la definición de tablas tienes ClienteID en una y clienteID en otra pero, en los querys sólo usas ClienteID de modo que podría haber una referencia mal escrita.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes simplemente añadir el cálculo a la tabla derivada que ya tienes en la consulta:

Por ejemplo:

```
Select TOP 1 
         p.*
       , d.COMPRAS
       , d.ValorMonetario
From (
    SELECT   a.ClienteID
           , SUM(Cantidad) as COMPRAS
           , sum(TotalPrice) as ValorMonetario
      from dbo.Venta a
     GROUP by a.ClienteID
    ) d inner join dbo.Cliente p on d.ClienteID = p.ClienteID
order by COMPRAS desc
```

Dicho esto, si bien una venta es una compra, vista del otro lado, te recomiendo no mezclar los términos dentro del código fuente... es mejor ver las cosas desde un solo punto de vista, al menos, a nivel del código. Esto, porque el total de la suma de la cantidad de la tabla de **ventas**, de pronto se llama **compras**. Eso lo hace confuso.

Otra cosa que haría es, si el motor lo soporta, utilizar un *CTE* en lugar de una tabla derivada. Es un cambio trivial al inicio, pero hace que la consulta sea más fácil de extender en el futuro.

```
with
ResumenVentas as (
SELECT   a.ClienteID
       , SUM(Cantidad) as CantidadVentas
       , sum(TotalPrice) as ValorVentas
  from dbo.Venta a
 GROUP by a.ClienteID
)
Select TOP 1 
         c.*
       , rv.CantidadVentas
       , rv.ValorVentas
 from ResumenVentas rv
      inner join dbo.Cliente c on c.ClienteID = rv.ClienteID
order by rv.CantidadVentas desc
```